# C++ check struct if its NULL or not set even if its have operator is equal

Tags: c++, struct, null

I have a struct that contains many members and also an operator overloading of == 
like this :

```
struct Adjustment {
    ObjectNumber aD;     
    Foo        afoo;  

    bool operator == (const Adjustment& aAdjustment) const
      { return (aAdjustment.ID == ID); }

  };
```

and when in code I have:

```
if(someAdjustment == NULL)
```

it gives me :

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Unit::Adjustment' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

So my question is, how can I check if this struct is set , without changing its code?

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen? You can't compare an object to `NULL`, only pointers (ok, you can compare integral types to `NULL` but lets not have that discussion here.)

Comment: What's the type of someAdjustment - if it's an object or a reference, the comparison is meaningless unless you have overloaded the operator == taking a pointer as the rhs.

Comment: it's an object that is passed as reference from function args

Comment: What is your definition of "set"?

Comment: References cannot be `NULL`!

Answer (score 2):

You may only compare a pointer to `NULL`. An Adjustment itself will never be NULL.

Comment: i just want to way to check if object is set

Comment: @user63898 you can not have an instance of Adjustment that is `not set`. There is no such term in `C++`.

Comment: @user63898 You can't, unless you give the class a means to know if it is set. or use `boost::optional<Adjustment>`.

Comment: @user63898 than create your own wrapper class that implements the optional functionality - it has to have a boolean flag and a member of the provided type.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev It's not a good idea to have a member of the type; what happens if the type has no default constructors?

Comment: ..and ensure that your wrapper-with-flag is properly and meaningfully default-initialized so that it's obvious when it been set and when not:)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - with a pointer you do not need a wrapper. Null pointer means nothing, a non-null pointer means a thing. Optionality-by-pointer is well established convention. Boost-optional was introduced so that noone mistakes a optional-by-pointer with provide-me-a-heap-allocated-object :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl but you will have to take care of allocating/deallocating the memory. That is the point of the wrapper. Also on a bare pointer you can't have methods while an `IsSet` method would make perfect sense here.

Comment: what? why? what allocationsif your magic wrapper with "a boolean flag and a member of the provided type" would contain a pointer, then either both I and you have to do allocations, or either noone of us has to:) It is not required to use any heap alloc-dealloc ops to just get a pointer! :))

Comment: all what I meant is that IF your magic-wrapper that is used instead of boost-optional is to be structured like:  "{ bool flag; T* pvalue;}" that you DO NOT NEED that flag. pValue=0 is enough to know it's empty, and such structure you implied when you said "sorry I meant a pointer of course" :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Actually, `boost::optional` was invented because the idiom was already widely used under the name `Fallible` (and I've seen `Maybe` as well---probably the best name, unless one wants to target one specific use).

Comment: Wow. Actually, for the last few years I've been somewhat "away" from C++, and even if I've actually seen `Maybe` - I've never heard/seen the `Fallible`. Strange name. Thank you very much! Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a "reference" denoted by `&` implies that the caller of your method is obligated to provide you with an object instance. There is no (NORMAL) way to call your method without an object. You are free to assume that you if your function is called, the aAdjustement will be set to something.

However, there are two gothas here:

(1) It will be set to something, but will that 'something' be meaningful? Is a Adjustement structure completely zeroed-out a valid value for your function? If not - then you may test that instead test nulliness. If any structure value combinations are invalid - use this as the discriminator. If all possible values are valid - then there's nothing to be checked.

(2) If you know the dark ways (tm), you actually CAN PASS a null-reference to this function. So your code is not "safe from nulls" just because "you used reference&". However, as I said, with use of & you clearly state that you disallow nulls. A caller that knows the dark ways(tm) may only blame himself when your function crashes.

disclaimer: "normal" and "the dark ways" are just buzzwords to hide extra complexity of a real professional explanation. If you play a bit with casting and */& operators, you will quickly discover how to get i.e. "int& boom" that would point to a zero-address. This is not so "dark" nor "magic", it's plain feature of the language and platform. However, (A) novice programmers and even somewhat experienced programmers tend to not know that references can be null, and (B) the convention of &-means-dont-pass-null is really well known and settled, so (A+B) please adapt to the convention and feel free to use it where adequate.